# Как сделать в регулярном выражении, чтобы она выбирала по первый пробел?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как сделать в регулярном выражении, чтобы она выбирала по первый пробел? 1,2,3 для примера, может быть любой текст, 0 также уникальная строка. Затем разбить группу нулём на начало и остальное до пробела . Например [(1цы)0(1цы)]пробел[(2ки)0(2ки)]пробел[(3ки)0(3ки)]
[image]

Comment: [`([^0]*0[^ ]*) ([^ ]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/UwQew8/1)

Comment: В своем регулярном выражение сделайте ленивыми квантификаторы `*` поставив после них знак вопроса `*?`

Comment: спасибо большое